# Здравствуйте, я новичок в программировании, не могу понять в чем проблема. Выдает ошибку:TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: Мне дали данную задачу]

Я решил так сказать отсеить из списка только те числа которые делятся либо на 3 либо на 5
тем самым оставив в списке только их, а затем суммировать получившиеся значения, но выдало ошибку
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable

Comment: А где ваш код? Он должен быть прямо в вопросе. Иначе можно только гадать, что вы не так сделали.

Comment: Прошу простить, сейчас добавлю.

Comment: Ну вы же сами в первой строке перезаписали функцию `range` объектом `(1,1001)`, потом этот объект пытаетесь вызвать как функцию. Просто удалите первую строку. P.S. ну и код нужно вставлять в вопрос текстом, а не скриншотом.

Comment: Я пытался сделать это и без первой строки но выводило уже другую ошибку

Comment: А именно: TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Comment: Ну так если у вас обычный цикл, то сумму вы должны обычным образом считать - завести переменную и добавлять в неё `i`. А функция `sum` принимает на вход итерируемые объекты, здесь она не подойдёт. Вот если бы у вас было *списковое сокращение*, то `sum` было бы удобно к нему применить.

Comment: понимаете у меня i это и есть переменная, как бы мне надо сделать так чтобы из списка от 1 до 1000 оставить только те числа которые делятся на 3 или 5 а затем данные полученного списка суммировать

Comment: `i` - это переменная цикла. А сумму надо хранить в другой переменной, например, `summ` её можете назвать, чтобы не перекрывать встроенную функцию `sum`.

Comment: просто я не понимаю как тогда решить данную задачу

Comment: А как бы вы на бумаге искали сумму чисел, если числа вам приходят по одному и вы каждое добавляете отдельно в общую сумму? Тут так же, только с переменной вместо бумаги. Вам просто нужна ещё одна переменная - в которой вы будете хранить текущую сумму.

Comment: У меня получается такой код;    summ=
for i in range (1,1001):
    if i//3 or i//5:
        summ=summ+i
print(summ).   Но я не знаю что присвоить переменной summ

Comment: Хотя можно было догадаться. Чему равна сумма, когда туда ещё ничего не добавили? )  Ну да вам уже подсказали.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых код нужно показывать в виде текста.
Нельзя называть переменные служебными именами (`range`).
Функция `sum()` складывает итерируемый объект `sum([1,2,3])=6`.
Чтобы суммировать переменную на каждой итерации, нужно в новую переменную добавлять новое значение переменной `i`, например `my_summa=my_summa+i`

Comment: Я вроде понял, но есть проблема, когда я создаю переменную summ мне надо ей присвоить какое либо значение чтобы не выдало ошибку summ is not defined. С этим проблема.  Ещё раз простите мне мою глупость если я что-то не понимаю.

Comment: @Мечтатель присвойте ей 0

Comment: Хорошо попробую

Comment: Спасибо Большое всем кто помог!

Comment: Программа наконец заработала! Большое всем спасибо и простите за потраченное время.